# How to get specific stub on multiple matching URL with different queryParameter

Tags: api, wiremock, stubbing

I have 2 WireMock mappings JSON files with same URL. In the first mapping JSON file, I only have a `xDate` as query parameter. In the 2nd mapping JSON file, I have the `xDate and yType` as query parameters.

How do I make the stub such that when I hit the URL with the 2 parameters, it will get the correct mapping/file information.

1st mapping json file:

```
"request" : {
    "customMatcher" : {
      "name" : "is-today",
      "parameters" : {
        "queryParamName" : "xDate",
        "dateFormat": "yyyy-MM-dd"
      }
    },
    "urlPathPattern" : "/myUrl",
    "method" : "GET"
  },
  "response" : {
    "status" : 200,
    "bodyFileName" : "body1.json",
    "headers" : {
      "Server" : "Apache-Coyote/1.1",
      "Content-Type" : "application/json"
    }
  }
```

2nd mapping json:

```
"request" : {
    "customMatcher" : {
      "name" : "is-today",
      "parameters" : {
        "queryParamName" : "xDate",
        "dateFormat": "yyyy-MM-dd"
      }
    },
    "queryParameters":{
      "yType" : {
        "equalTo": "Value"
      }
    },
    "urlPathPattern" : "/myUrl",
    "method" : "GET"
  },
  "response" : {
    "status" : 200,
    "bodyFileName" : "body2.json",
    "headers" : {
      "Server" : "Apache-Coyote/1.1",
      "Content-Type" : "application/json"
    }
  }
```

When I was testing it, it always hits the 1st mapping JSON. When I tried to hit the URL with 2 input parameters, it always go to the 1st mapping.

Tried putting the "priority" value on 1st and 2nd mapping file but somehow, its not working properly for me.